# Angular UI uib-typeahead results not showing in dropdown

Tags: angularjs-directive, typeahead

I have gone through the previous solutions but that did not help to resolve my issue. I'm trying to display the list of user details in typeahead. I'm getting an error like below and results from API call gets printed in console log but did not show up in the dropdown.

in my controller:

```
$scope.getUserDetails = function (id, value) {
            var myUrl = '//myAPIcall?id=1&value=xxx';

                return $http.get(myUrl).then(function successCallback(response) {                     
                      return response.data.userOptions[0].userOptionValues.map(function(item) {
                          console.log('item.userValue = '+item.userValue);
                          $scope.getUserDetails = item.userValue;
                          return item.userValue;
                      });
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                      console.log(response);
                    });             
        };
```

in my html:

```
<input id="inputText"
type="text"    
name="filter"
class="form-control"    
data-ng-model="selectedVal"
uib-typeahead="item.userValue for item in getUserDetails(1,$viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10 "
typeahead-template="displayTemplate.html"/>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="displayTemplate.html">
<a>
<span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
</a>
</script>
```

Error: 
[filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22%24%24state%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A0%7D%7D
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:149
    at Object.fn [as source] (eval at compile (angular.min.js:212), :4:610)
    at getMatchesAsync (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.0.min.js:6747)
    at ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.0.min.js:6845
    at angular.min.js:146
    at e (angular.min.js:43)
    at angular.min.js:45

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something wonky is going on with:

```
return response.data.userOptions[0].userOptionValues.map(function(item) {
    console.log('item.userValue = '+item.userValue);
    $scope.getUserDetails = item.userValue; // (1)
    return item.userValue;   // (2)
```

});

1) You're resetting $scope.getUserDetails to a single value, which will be overwriting the $scope.getUserDetails = function(...) line.

2) You're returning an array of single values, but in your uib-typeahead you're attempting to use the item.userValue, but because of this line `item = item.userValue`

Anything else it's hard to tell without more info or example data.